# SQLAlchemy : How to compile function like sql.func.std

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i want to make small changes to the sql.func.std 
i want to return a different value when std result is nan

using this code :

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FunctionElement

class std(FunctionElement):
    name = 'std'


@compiles(std)
def compile(element, compiler, **kw):
    elem = compiler.process(element.clauses)
    return "if(isnan(std(%s)), 0, std(%s))" % (elem, elem)


t1 = sql.select([sql.literal("1").label('a')]).alias('t1')

q = sql.select([std(t1.c.a)]).select_from(t1)
```

result is as expected

```
SELECT if(isnan(std(t1.a)), 0, std(t1.a)) FROM (SELECT '1' AS a) AS t1
```

while using this query

```
q = sql.select([sql.func.std(t1.c.a)]).select_from(t1)
```

result is wrong

```
SELECT std(t1.a) AS std_1 FROM (SELECT '1' AS a) AS t1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to register generic functions that are accessible from [`func`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) you should base your function on [`GenericFunction`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.GenericFunction) instead of `FunctionElement`:

```
In [6]: from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import GenericFunction
   ...: 
   ...: class std(GenericFunction):
   ...:     name = 'std'
   ...: 

In [8]: q = select([func.std(t1.c.a)]).select_from(t1)

In [9]: print(q)
SELECT if(isnan(std(t1.a)), 0, std(t1.a)) AS std_1 
FROM (SELECT :param_1 AS a) AS t1
```